# Grabing video and image from a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a bookmarklet in JavaScript to grab images and videos from a HTML page. I easily grabbed all the images very easily like,

```
$('img', $('body'))
```

Now i want to grab all the videos embedded in a web page from different sources like Youtube, Vimeo, Dailymotion etc., So can someone give some idea about how to achieve this with some sample JavaScript code?

Note: I just need to get the links of embedded videos from external sites.

Comment: By grabbing, do you mean getting the links to said videos, or actually saving them? If the latter, you won't be able to save videos from the sites you mentioned using just Javascript.

Comment: $('iframe','object','video') may be..

Comment: @Renan Added a note for you...

Answer (score 1):

Youtube for example lets you embed videos either with an `<object>` tag, which is the old version, or with an iframe. Vimeo gives you the embedded video in an iframe, too.
So by selecting all `<iframe>` and `<embed>` elements you can easily get the video links from them by selecting them with the following code:

```
var videos = $('iframe, embed');
```

Edith: the actual video link is in the `src` tag, both with an iframe and an embed object.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed the videos using an `<iframe>`, you can use the "[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
var videos = $('iframe[src^="http://youtube.com"]');
```

This will select all embedded videos from YouTube for example.

**Edit**

As you said, you want all videos from external Sites, this should work:

```
var host = $(location).attr('host');
var videos = $('iframe:not([src^="http://' + host + '"])');
```

Comment: It won't select those in `<object>` tags, though.

Comment: As the OP didn't mention how he embeds the videos I assumed that he's probably using `<iframe>`s. You can easily adopt the selector to also select `<object>`-tags.